# C Program are closing automatically

Tags: c

I created a C Program that will take all the order of the user then generate the grandtotal of the orders.

But when I will order another food, the program is closing automatically.

I don't know if this is about my getch or the breaks in my switch method. Sometimes, it will proceed to take another error but it automatically outputs "INVALID FOOD".

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>

void menu();
void foods();
void main();
char food;
int quantity;
float price;
float total;
float grandtotal;
int choice;

void main()
{
    clrscr();
    menu();

    foods();
    getch();
}

void menu(){

    food = ' ';
    quantity = 0;
    price = 0;
    total = 0;
    choice = 0;
    printf("Please select food from the following:\n");
    printf(" B = Burger, F = French Fries, P = Pizza, S = Sandwiches \n");

    printf("Enter food:");
    scanf("%c", &food);
}

void foods(){
    switch(food)
    {
        case 'B':
            printf("You selected Burger!\n");
            printf("Enter quantity:");
            scanf("%d", &quantity);
            price = 95.50;

            printf("\n Do you want to order more? [1] Yes [2] No:");
            scanf("%d", &choice);

            total = price*quantity;

            if(choice == 1){
                menu();
                break;
            }
            else if (choice == 2){
                grandtotal = grandtotal + total;
                printf("\n Total Price is: %0.2f", grandtotal);
                break;
            }

        case 'F':
            printf("You selected French Fries!\n");
            printf("Enter quantity:");
            scanf("%d", &quantity);
            price = 47.75;

            printf("\n Do you want to order more? [1] Yes [2] No:");
            scanf("%d", &choice);

            total = price*quantity;
            if(choice == 1){
                menu();
                break;
            }
            else if (choice == 2){
                grandtotal = grandtotal + total;
                printf("\n Total Price is: %0.2f", grandtotal);
                break;
            }

        case 'P':
            printf("You selected French Pizza!\n");
            printf("Enter quantity:");
            scanf("%d", &quantity);
            price = 105.00;

            printf("\n Do you want to order more? [1] Yes [2] No:");
            scanf("%d", &choice);

            total = price*quantity;
            if(choice == 1){
                menu();
                break;
            }
            else if (choice == 2){
                grandtotal = grandtotal + total;
                printf("\n Total Price is: %0.2f", grandtotal);
                break;
            }

        case 'S':
            printf("You selected Sandwiches\n");
            printf("Enter quantity:");
            scanf("%d", &quantity);
            price = 75.50;

            printf("\n Do you want to order more? [1] Yes [2] No:");
            scanf("%d", &choice);

            total = price*quantity;
            if(choice == 1){
                main();
                break;
            }
            else if (choice == 2){
                grandtotal = grandtotal + total;
                printf("\n Total Price is: %0.2f", grandtotal);
                break;
            }

            default:
            printf("INVALID FOOD!");
            break;

    }
}
```

I wish someone could help or guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all: [indent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) your code properly.

Comment: TurboC is an obsolete, non-standard conforming, implementation of C.  Consider using something better (perhaps [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), e.g. as [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) on Windows). Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Be aware that C and C++ are *different* programming languages. The `\n` should be at *end* of `printf` format, since `stdout` could be line-buffered.

Comment: I'm really not a fan of how your `menu` functions calls `main`.

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but the overall structure of your program is very poor and the usage of global variables is at least questionable.

Comment: Sorry @Jabberwocky. This is noted, I will indent it properly.

I am wondering why it's closing automatically :(

Comment: Sorry sirs, I am just new to programming. I just used my brother's stackoverflow account to seek some guides. This is my first hands on exam in C programming.

Comment: Nothing to be sorry for, you are at the right place. The comments about the Turbo C/C++ compiler are important, especially if your are relying on older documentation related to that compiler. Literally the Borland Turbo C/C++ compiler is circa 1990 (and a few version updates from a couple of years later, but decades before the Current C standard and before any meaningful C++ standard). Which, unless your hardware is an implementation defined embedded system, the `void main()` is not a valid program startup for conforming compilers.

Comment: After taking a look at your program, I decided to show you a neater way to do it.  This is not bullet-proof or beautiful code by any means, but hopefully you will see it's by far easier to maintain.  https://ideone.com/QVfKas

Comment: Thanks everyone for reminding all of these, very appreciated. 

@paddy I tried your code suggestion and it displays error "function iispace should have prototype" upon compiling.

Comment: You need to include `<ctype.h>` -- https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call menu after user input is [1] yes. with menu() function show menu and after menu you should show call food() function.

HERE WHAT YOU WANT

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>

void menu();
void foods();
void main();
char food;
int quantity;
float price;
float total;
float grandtotal;
int choice;

void main()
{


    clrscr();
    do {
        menu();
        foods();

        printf("\n Do you want to order more? [1] Yes [2] No:");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        getchar();  // <== remove newline
        grandtotal = grandtotal + total;
    } while (choice == 1);

        printf("\n Total Price is: %0.2f", grandtotal);
    getch();
}

void menu() {

    food = ' ';
    quantity = 0;
    price = 0;
    total = 0;
    choice = 0;
    printf("Please select food from the following:\n");
    printf(" B = Burger, F = French Fries, P = Pizza, S = Sandwiches \n");

    printf("Enter food:");
    scanf("%c", &food);
}

void foods() {
    switch (food)
    {
    case 'B':
        printf("You selected Burger!\n");
        printf("Enter quantity:");
        scanf("%d", &quantity);
        price = 95.50;

        //printf("\n Do you want to order more? [1] Yes [2] No:");
        //scanf("%d", &choice);
        //getchar();  // <== remove newline

        total = price*quantity;
        break;

        //if (choice == 1) {

        //  menu();
        //  break;
        //}
        //else if (choice == 2) {
        //  grandtotal = grandtotal + total;
        //  printf("\n Total Price is: %0.2f", grandtotal);
        //  break;
        //}

    case 'F':
        printf("You selected French Fries!\n");
        printf("Enter quantity:");
        scanf("%d", &quantity);
        price = 47.75;

        //printf("\n Do you want to order more? [1] Yes [2] No:");
        //scanf("%d", &choice);

        total = price*quantity;
        break;
        //if (choice == 1) {
        //  menu();
        //  break;
        //}
        //else if (choice == 2) {
        //  grandtotal = grandtotal + total;
        //  printf("\n Total Price is: %0.2f", grandtotal);
        //  break;
        //}

    case 'P':
        printf("You selected French Pizza!\n");
        printf("Enter quantity:");
        scanf("%d", &quantity);
        price = 105.00;

        //printf("\n Do you want to order more? [1] Yes [2] No:");
        //scanf("%d", &choice);

        total = price*quantity;
        break;
        //if (choice == 1) {
        //  menu();
        //  break;
        //}
        //else if (choice == 2) {
        //  grandtotal = grandtotal + total;
        //  printf("\n Total Price is: %0.2f", grandtotal);
        //  break;
        //}

    case 'S':
        printf("You selected Sandwiches\n");
        printf("Enter quantity:");
        scanf("%d", &quantity);
        price = 75.50;

        //printf("\n Do you want to order more? [1] Yes [2] No:");
        //scanf("%d", &choice);

        total = price*quantity;
        break;
        //if (choice == 1) {
        //  main();
        //  break;
        //}
        //else if (choice == 2) {
        //  grandtotal = grandtotal + total;
        //  printf("\n Total Price is: %0.2f", grandtotal);
        //  break;
        //}

    default:
        printf("INVALID FOOD!");
        break;

    }
}
```

Comment: Sir this revision really works! I will put down all your advises in the comments! 

The only problem left is it is not displaying the proper grandtotal when I decided not to order again, it only displays the total of the last order.

Comment: OK, now check it again @ASCII

Comment: Thanks a lot! @amin

Answer (score 3):

In you code you have duplicated multiple times:

```
...
if(choice == 1){
   menu();
   break;
} ...
...
```

So when you choose `choice = 1` then `menu()` get's displayed, and then the code breaks out of `foods()`. I think you meant to do the foods section again:

```
...
if(choice == 1){
   menu();
   foods();
   break;
} ...
...
```

Yet another problem in your code is the `%c` scanf modifier. It will not eat up leading whitespaces, so it will read a newline (inputted on the last scanf). Use a leading space `" %c"` to tell scanf to read up leading whitespaces and ignore the leading newline, in `scanf(" %c", &food);`

1. Indent your code.
2. Don't duplicate statements. The whole `scanf(... &choice); if (choice == 1) ... else if (choice == 2)` could be placed outside the `while` switch not beeing duplicated 4 times.
3. Nesting functions using recursive calls can make your stack run out. Better just use a while loop.
4. Try not to use global variables. They are misleading and lead to maintainable code.

A slightly modified version of you code with a bit of indententation, added a `do ... while` loop and removed global variables and code duplication, may look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

char menu(void);
float foods(char food);

void main()
{
    clrscr();

    float grandtotal = 0;

    int choice = 0;
    do {
        // print menu and choose the food
        char food = menu();
        // choose food quantity and get it's price
        float total = foods(food);

        // print the total price
        grandtotal = grandtotal + total;
        printf("\n Total Price is: %0.2f", grandtotal);

        // do you want to continue?
        printf("\n Do you want to order more? [1] Yes [2] No:");
        if (scanf("%d", &choice) != 1) {
            perror("scanf error");
            abort();
        }

        // continue until choice is equal to 1
    } while (choice != 1);
}

char menu(void)
{
    char food;
    printf("Please select food from the following:\n");
    printf(" B = Burger, F = French Fries, P = Pizza, S = Sandwiches \n");
    printf("Enter food:");
    if (scanf(" %c", &food) != 1) {
        perror("scanf error");
        abort();
    }
    return food;
}

float foods(char food){
    float price = 0;
    switch (food) {
    case 'B':
        printf("You selected Burger!\n");
        price = 95.50;
        break;
    case 'F':
        printf("You selected French Fries!\n");
        price = 47.75;
        break;
    case 'P':
        printf("You selected French Pizza!\n");
        price = 105.00;
        break;
    case 'S':
        printf("You selected Sandwiches\n");
        price = 75.50;
        break;
    default:
        fprintf(stderr, "INVALID FOOD!\n");
        abort();
    }

    printf("Enter quantity:");
    int quantity;
    if (scanf("%d", &quantity) != 1) {
        perror("scanf error");
        abort();
    }

    return (float)price * (float)quantity;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this sir, I did your suggestion but it still close after I choose 1 when asking me if I want to order more.

Comment: Right, `%c` in scanf returns a newline.