# Don't getchar function print the second input?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char gh, hj;
    printf("Enter the first letter of your name \n");
    gh=getchar();
    printf("Enter the last letter of your name\n");
    hj=getchar();
    getchar();
    printf("The first and last leter of your name is %c%c", gh, hj);
    return 0;

}
```

When I run this code the second `%c` doesn't get printed, unlike the first one. Why is this happening?

Comment: Because the 2nd `getchar` reads the newline character after the character you entered.

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53701746/7032512

Answer (score 1):

Since the second `getchar` peruses the newline character after the character you entered.